# Order x axis (number of month)

Tags: r, axis

I have a dataframe as following

```
year month increment  
113 6 464  
113 7 132  
113 8 165  
113 9 43 
113 10 658  
113 11  54  
113 12 463  
114 1  231  
114 2 21
```

Despite being ordered as indicated, when I plot increment~factor(month), the resulting x axis in the plot starts from month 1, instead of starting with month 6 like the dataframe

```
qplot(month,data=monthly,fill=treatment,weight=increment,position="dodge")
```

What should I do to make x axis respect the order of the month I need?

Comment: In general, the order of the data in your data frame has _no connection_ to how it will be displayed. (There are exceptions, but they are rare.)

Comment: You're missing part of your data, namely treatment, in your example.  How would `fill=treatment` if it does not exist?

Comment: Also, even though your year column is strangely formatted, you might want to read up on `as.date` in base or some of the very useful packages for date/time handling: `lubridate`, `chron`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
qplot(interaction(year, month, lex.order=TRUE), data=monthly, fill=treatment,weight=increment,position="dodge")
```

Removing the `fill=treatment` argument (as I do not have the data) results in this:

```
qplot(interaction(year, month, lex.order=TRUE), data=monthly, weight=increment,position="dodge")
```

[image]